# Group By - Erro de agregação?

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

boa tarde!
De saída, agradeço pelo tempo de todos. Estou iniciando no SQL (e na programação como um todo!).

Na minha base, eu tenho várias linhas para o NRPROT com preços diferentes, valores de baixa e recurso diferentes. O que eu preciso é agrupar o NRPROT e seus respectivos valores. Não sei se ficou claro... mas eu montei a consulta que está abaixo e o Access não permite. Diz que estão faltando valores para agregação. Eu devo colocar todas as colunas que estão no select?

```
SELECT 
  NRPROT,
  CODCONTR, 
  MARCA, 
  NRPROT, 
  DTPGTO, 
  VALORRECURSO, 
  VALORBAIXA, 
  VLRGLO, 
  VLRGLO * 0.47 AS NEGOCIACAO_RECURSO, 
  VLRGLO * 0.53 AS NEGOCIACAO_BAIXA 
FROM TESTE_1
GROUP BY NRPROT;
```

Comment: o "group by"  pede que você coloque todos os campos que estão antes do From, na ordem que você deseja agrupar

Comment: Obrigado! Não sabia desse "detalhe". rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa o [`Group By`](https://www.devmedia.com.br/desvendando-a-clausula-group-by-artigo-sql-magazine-47/8082), todas as colunas que serão únicas no *select* devem ser usadas para o agrupamento.

Por exemplo, se você quer saber quantos alunos têm a mesma idade e moram no mesmo país, sua consulta seria algo como

```
SELECT idade, pais, count(*) as total
FROM alunos
GROUP BY idade, pais
```

---

Sendo assim, sua consulta só precisa adicionar mais cláusulas ao *`group by`*:

```
SELECT 
  NRPROT, CODCONTR, MARCA, NRPROT, DTPGTO, VALORRECURSO, VALORBAIXA, VLRGLO, 
  VLRGLO * 0.47 AS NEGOCIACAO_RECURSO, VLRGLO * 0.53 AS NEGOCIACAO_BAIXA 
FROM TESTE_1
GROUP BY NRPROT, CODCONTR, MARCA, NRPROT, DTPGTO, VALORRECURSO, VALORBAIXA, VLRGLO
```